# Is any issue scan long period of Android AltBeacon Library?

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon

I use altbeacon library to scan BLE Kit.

When I use method like this,

```
@Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {

                Log.d("BeaconInfo","" + collection.size);


            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(defaultRegion);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

It worked normally at first time, but after five minutes or long, It occurs error like, like when I select button to load video file or image file from server, or I reload that activity which is scan BLE Kit, It returns collection size is 0.

I did when do another thing, I should use this method.

```
private void stopBeacon(){

        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }
```

When I start the App first time, it returns collection size normally but I stay about 3minutues, occurs error.

I don't understand of it

If you know about of it, please help me

---

```
    BeaconManager beaconManager;
Button button;

@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainr);

    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    button.setOnClickLister(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                        moveList();
                    }
         });

            startBeacon();
           }


    @Override
     public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

            beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
                @Override
                public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {

                Log.d("BeaconInfo","" + collection.size());

             }
         });

            try {
                    beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(defaultRegion);
             } catch (RemoteException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }

      }


    private void startBeacon(){
                beaconManager.bind(this);
            }

    private void stopBeacon(){  
                beaconManager.unbind(this);
            }

public void moveList(){

        stopBeacon();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ListActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);

        finish();

    }
```

Comment: Can you please show all the code of your Activity?  It may be a lifecycle problem in binding/unbinding to the beacon scanning service.

Comment: @davidgyoung Edit my question. please see that. It is not special because it's sample.

Comment: @davidgyoung I don't think life cycle because It's so simple

Comment: I suspect that repeatedly calling bind() and unbind()  is problematic, as it creates multiple instances of the RangeNotifier and registers it each time it connects.  I would rework the code to bind in onResume(), unbind in onPause().

Comment: @davidgyoung Thanks but I already did it before. In onResume, put beaconManager.bind(this), in onStop and onPause, put beaconManager.unbind(this).

Comment: If you want to try to get the code working as-is, you'll need to troubleshoot the timing of each method call and figure out the sequence of events that causes it to break.  I'd add  a Log.d statement at the top of each method shown, and then look for the sequence of method calls that happens right before it stops detecting.